# Vim: how to highlite folds with cursorline?

Tags: vim, folding

Is there a possibility to highlite current line with cursorline over folding highlite?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the closed fold color wins over the cursorline/cursorcolumn highlight

You could try to use signs (:he sign.txt) to do your job if you are determined. Also see ShowMarks plugin

Check :version to see whether +signs was compiled in

Oh, of course you'd have autocommands to update the sign (define it for the current line ('.)) and see updatetime setting as well